# Conditional Statements in SQL IF/ELSE

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements

I'm trying to get a conditional statement right in T-SQL, by Microsoft's documentation this is what they have:

```
IF Boolean_expression   
     { sql_statement | statement_block }   
[ ELSE   
     { sql_statement | statement_block } ]
```

My query:

```
IF CVD_OWNER.CVD_RESIDENT_STAFF_DTL.HRCHY_DTL_SK = 0 {
    SELECT FIRST_NM, MIDDLE_INITIAL, LAST_NM,
    DOB, GENDER, MBI, RACE1, RACE2, RACE3, RACE4, RACE5, RACE6,
    ETHINICITY, DOSE_NBR, COMORBIDITY_STATUS
} [ ELSE  {
    SELECT FIRST_NM, MIDDLE_INITIAL, LAST_NM,
    DOB, GENDER, MBI, RACE1, RACE2, RACE3, RACE4, RACE5, RACE6,
    ETHINICITY, DOSE_NBR, COMORBIDITY_STATUS,LTCF_NAME, CCN_NBR, 
    CVD_LTCF_HRCHY_DTL.PHONE, CVD_LTCF_HRCHY_DTL.PHONE_TYP,
    ADMIN_EMAIL, CVD_LTCF_HRCHY_DTL.ADDR_LINE1, CVD_LTCF_HRCHY_DTL.ADDR_LINE2,
    CVD_LTCF_HRCHY_DTL.CITY, CVD_LTCF_HRCHY_DTL.ST, CVD_LTCF_HRCHY_DTL.ZIP, LTCF_TYP
} ],
CVD_LTCF_HRCHY_DTL.CITY, CVD_LTCF_HRCHY_DTL.ST, CVD_LTCF_HRCHY_DTL.ZIP, LTCF_TYP
FROM CVD_OWNER.CVD_RESIDENT_STAFF_DTL
LEFT JOIN CVD_OWNER.CVD_LTCF_HRCHY_DTL
ON CVD_OWNER.CVD_RESIDENT_STAFF_DTL.HRCHY_DTL_SK = CVD_OWNER.CVD_LTCF_HRCHY_DTL.HRCHY_DTL_SK
WHERE CAND_DATA_SENT = 'N';
```

In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I get these errors when trying to run this query:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
> Incorrect syntax near '{'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
> Incorrect syntax near '}'.
>
> Msg 103, Level 15, State 4, Line 16
> The identifier that starts with ' ELSE  {
> SELECT FIRST_NM, MIDDLE_INITIAL, LAST_NM,
> DOB, GENDER, MBI, RACE1, RACE2, RACE3, RACE4, RACE5, RACE6,
> ETHINICITY,' is too long. Maximum length is 128.

I don't understand how my syntax is incorrect when I'm seemingly using exactly what the documentation shows me.

Comment: *"I don't understand how my syntax is incorrect"* Because it isn't. Braces (`{}`) aren't part of T-SQL Syntax, and brackets (`[]`) are delimit identifiers. Have a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), that shows you the format.

Comment: This is not the full and actual query and you should learn how to use the computer science book/online documentation. The notation `[]` is used for showing the optional values and `<>` indicates here you have to replace the word as per your condition.

Comment: Thank you! I won't even need to write the conditionals though. There's an easier and nicer work around.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are trying to do an if/else block like the following

```
IF (CVD_OWNER.CVD_RESIDENT_STAFF_DTL.HRCHY_DTL_SK = 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        FIRST_NM, MIDDLE_INITIAL, LAST_NM,
        DOB, GENDER, MBI, RACE1, RACE2, RACE3, RACE4, RACE5, RACE6,
        ETHINICITY, DOSE_NBR, COMORBIDITY_STATUS,CVD_LTCF_HRCHY_DTL.CITY, 
        CVD_LTCF_HRCHY_DTL.ST, CVD_LTCF_HRCHY_DTL.ZIP, LTCF_TYP
    FROM CVD_OWNER.CVD_RESIDENT_STAFF_DTL
    LEFT JOIN CVD_OWNER.CVD_LTCF_HRCHY_DTL
        ON CVD_OWNER.CVD_RESIDENT_STAFF_DTL.HRCHY_DTL_SK = CVD_OWNER.CVD_LTCF_HRCHY_DTL.HRCHY_DTL_SK
    WHERE CAND_DATA_SENT = 'N';
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        FIRST_NM, MIDDLE_INITIAL, LAST_NM,
        DOB, GENDER, MBI, RACE1, RACE2, RACE3, RACE4, RACE5, RACE6,
        ETHINICITY, DOSE_NBR, COMORBIDITY_STATUS,LTCF_NAME, CCN_NBR, 
        CVD_LTCF_HRCHY_DTL.PHONE, CVD_LTCF_HRCHY_DTL.PHONE_TYP,
        ADMIN_EMAIL, CVD_LTCF_HRCHY_DTL.ADDR_LINE1, CVD_LTCF_HRCHY_DTL.ADDR_LINE2,
        CVD_LTCF_HRCHY_DTL.CITY, CVD_LTCF_HRCHY_DTL.ST, CVD_LTCF_HRCHY_DTL.ZIP, LTCF_TYP,
        CVD_LTCF_HRCHY_DTL.CITY, CVD_LTCF_HRCHY_DTL.ST, CVD_LTCF_HRCHY_DTL.ZIP, LTCF_TYP
    FROM CVD_OWNER.CVD_RESIDENT_STAFF_DTL
    LEFT JOIN CVD_OWNER.CVD_LTCF_HRCHY_DTL
    ON CVD_OWNER.CVD_RESIDENT_STAFF_DTL.HRCHY_DTL_SK = CVD_OWNER.CVD_LTCF_HRCHY_DTL.HRCHY_DTL_SK
    WHERE CAND_DATA_SENT = 'N';
END;
```